# Cannot validate boolean field if value = false (missing field)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I can't validate POST data with boolean field value "false" only, this works fine with "true". I was already try to force '0', 'False' and 'false' but is_valid() method return false with error "This field is required".

My post data dict is :

```
<QueryDict: {u'vote': [u'false'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'l3RlmeHDnv7Y5aQiNJoadLUZDsiOFUI'], u'id': [u'40']}>
```

If I post 'true' value for this field, the QueryDict is exactly the same, just 'false' is changing.

I tried to convert into str instead of unicode dict, but it's not working.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would need to parse the input from a string to bool value. The following: `bool('false')` and `bool('true')` will always return `True` due to their implicit [truthiness and falseness](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) respectively.

```
def to_bool(s):
    return s.lower() == 'true'
```

**Sample output:**

```
d = {u'vote': [u'false']}
print to_bool(d['vote'][0]) 
>>> False
```

Comment: It's possible. But what is correct form response for boolean field ? In my JS code, I just return a test result.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** : 
Using NullBooleanField instead of BooleanField...